# Prove / disprove: If $1 \le n < N$ and $A$ is an $N \times n$ matrix with iid from $\mathcal N(0,1)$, then $s_\min(A) \ge c\sqrt{N}$ w.p $1-2e^{-N}$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $1 \le n < N$ be integers and $A$ be a random $N\times n$ matrix with iid entries from $\mathcal N(0,1)$. This [paper (Rudelson and Vershynin)](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/rv-ICM2010.pdf) claims in the paragraph just  before formula (3.4) that, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$
P(s_\min(A) \ge c\sqrt{N}) \ge 1 - 2e^{-CN},\text{ with }C=1! \tag{1}
$$

I doubt the validity of the above statement with $C=1$.

**Note.** I know that the statement can be made true with a smaller value of $C$ (and some mild conditions on the aspect ratio $n/N$).

> **Question.** Can someone kindly rollout the sketch of a proof of (1), or else disprove it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe Rudelson and Vershynin are only claiming this bound in the regime of tall matrices (in which the ratio $n/N$ is assumed to be sufficiently small).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you kindly provide a hight-level justification why this ought to be true for all $n/N < \lambda_0$, for some constant $\lambda_0 \in (0,1)$ ?

Comment: It's true (for any $C$, if $c$ is sufficiently small depending on $C$) for each individual column (i.e., for $n$=1) by direct calculation of the chi-squared distribution (or evaluating the measure that an $N$-dimensional gaussian gives to a small ball around the origin), and the epsilon net argument (see e.g., https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/254a-notes-7-the-least-singular-value/ ) then extends this bound to tall matrices (again for any $C$, if $c,\lambda_0$ are small enough depending on $C$.)

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks for the crucial hint (namely, "small-ball probabilities"). Below, I've posted an answer putting every thing together.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I provide an answer inspired by the comments of user Terry Tao.

---

Let $n/N =: \lambda \in (0, 1)$ be the aspect ratio of $A$. We will prove the following.

> **Claim.** *For every $C>0$, there exists $c>0$ depending only on $\lambda$ and $C$ such that $s_\min(A) \ge c\sqrt{N}$ w.p $1-2e^{-CN}$.*

### Technical tools

For any positive integer $k$, let $\mathbb B_k := \{x \in \mathbb R^k \text{ s.t } \|x\| \le 1\}$ be the unit-ball in $k$-dimensional euclidean space $\mathbb R^k$ and let $\mathbb S_{k-1} := \{x \in \mathbb R^k \text{ s.t } \|x\| = 1\}$ be the corresponding unit-sphere.

> **Fact 1 (Gaussian small-ball probability).** *If $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_k) \sim \mathcal N(0,I_k)$, then there exists $C_1>0$ such that $P(\|X\| \le u \sqrt{k}) \le (C_1u)^k$ for all $u \ge 0$.*

*Proof.* For every $u \ge 0$, one computes
$$
P(\|X\| \le u \sqrt{k}) = (2\pi)^{-k/2}\int_{u\sqrt{k} \mathbb B_k}e^{-\|x\|^2}dx \le (2\pi)^{-k/2}\mbox{vol}(u\sqrt{k}\mathbb B_k) \le (C_1u)^k,
$$
for some $C_1>0$ (which can be made explicit).

> **Fact 2 (Spectral-norm upper bound).** *For every $C>0$, there exists $C_0>0$ such that $s_{\max}(A) \le C_0\sqrt{N}$ w.p $1-e^{-CN}$.*

*Proof.* See **Fact 2.4** of this [paper by Litvak, Pajor, and Rudelson](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Erudelson/papers/rand-matr.pdf).

### Proof of the main claim

We are now ready to proof the main claim.

*Proof of the main claim.*  Let $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$, to be prescribed later, and let  $\mathcal N_\epsilon$ be a maximal $\epsilon$-net for $\mathbb S_{n-1}$. Note that $|\mathcal N_\epsilon| \le (3/\epsilon)^n = (3/\epsilon)^{\lambda N}$. Now, for each $x \in \mathbb S_{n-1}$, there exists $z \in \mathcal N_\epsilon$ such that $\|x-z\| \le \epsilon$. Writing $Ax = Az + A(x -z)$, the triangle inequality gives us $\|Ax\| \ge \|Az\| - \|A(x-z)\| \ge \|Az\|-\epsilon s_\max(A)$. Minimizing both sides, we obtain

$$
s_\min(A) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\|Ax\| \ge \min_{z \in \mathcal N_\epsilon}\|Az\|-\epsilon s_\max(A).\tag{1}
$$

Let $C_1$ be as in **Fact 1** with $k=N$. For arbitrary $C>0$, let $C_0$ be as in **Fact 2** with $k=N$, and let $c > 0$, to be carefully chosen later. By (1),  we know that if $s_\max(A) \le C_0\sqrt{N}$ and  $\|Az\| \ge 2c \sqrt{N}$ for all $z \in \mathcal N_\epsilon$, then $s_\min(A) \ge 2c\sqrt{N}-\epsilon C_0\sqrt{N} \ge c\sqrt{N}$ when $\epsilon = c/C_0$ with $c <  C_0$. Thus,

$$
\begin{split}
&P(s_\min(A) < c\sqrt{N}) \\
&\quad= P(s_\min(A) < c \sqrt{N},s_\max(A) > C_0\sqrt{N})\\
&\quad\quad\quad+ P(s_\min(A) > C_0\sqrt{N},s_\max(A) \le C_0\sqrt{N})\\
&\quad\le P(s_\max(A) > C_0\sqrt{N}) + P(s_\min(A) < c \sqrt{N},s_\max(A) \le C_0\sqrt{N})\\
&\quad \le e^{-CN} + P(\min_{z \in \mathcal N_\epsilon}\|Az\| < 2c\sqrt{N}) \le e^{-CN} + |\mathcal N_\epsilon|\cdot\max_{z \in \mathcal N_\epsilon}P(\|Az\| \le 2c\sqrt{N})\\
&\quad \le e^{-CN} + (3/\epsilon)^n(C_1 \cdot 2c)^N \le e^{-CN}+((3/\epsilon)^\lambda\cdot C_1\cdot 2c)^N\\
&\quad\le e^{-CN} + (2C_1(3C_0/c)^\lambda c)^N \le e^{-CN} + e^{-CN}=2e^{-C N},
\end{split}
$$
for sufficiently small $c \in (0,C_0)$ such that $2C_1(3C_0/c)^\lambda c < e^{-C}$.

Therefore, given arbitrary $C>0$, the bound $P(s_\min(A) \le c\sqrt{N}) \le 2e^{-CN}$ is guaranteed by taking $c \in (0,c_\lambda(C))$, where
$$
\begin{split}
c_\lambda(C) := \min(C_0,(2C_1e^C(3C_0)^\lambda)^{\frac{-1}{1-\lambda}})>0.
\end{split}
\tag{2}
$$

This completes the proof of the claim. $\quad\quad\Box$

**Note.** An important highlight the above proof is that it works for every aspect ratio $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

### Going beyond Gaussian matrices

A careful inspection of the proof of main ingredients **Fact 1** and **Fact 2**, reveals that we can replace the base distribution $N(0,1)$ of the coefficients of $A$ by any symmetric unit-variance $\sigma^2$-subGaussian such that $0 \le \sigma \le 1$.